# How to empty all contents of a Django table in a management command before filling it with new data

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I am quite new to Django so forgive me if this is an easy answer. I'm creating a simple app that will display data that I scrape from the web on a daily basis. This will be pricing data for certain items; so basically on a daily basis, the only thing that would really change would be the price of a given item. Eventually, I will have an app that contains an HTML table in which I will populate an item ID as well as its price using only the data that is scraped for the current day... i.e any item ID in the table should appear only once and have today's price. I want to keep historical data for another app where I will display prices over time.

I set up a management command which will run the scraper for me and dump my data into the sqlite database and am also using django-simple-history to store historical data. The way I understand this is working is my scraper dumps my data into both the table that I created (model_data) as well as a historical table (model_historicaldata).

What I am hoping my scraper will do on a daily basis is EMPTY the model_data table - since it will already be in the historical table anyways (not delete the entire table itself) and then proceed with filling it up with only the current day's data. The model_historicaldata table should remain untouched at this stage.

Current at the beginning of my management command I have model.objects.all().delete(). This seems to work when displaying only today's data via the HTML template, however when querying the model_data in the shell I am still seeing the total count of all items (3000 in this case when I only scraped 1500 today).

```
# Empty existing table to fill with only current days data
    if model_data.objects.all().delete():
        print("Yesterday's data cleared. Scraping today's data.")
    else:
        print("Could not empty yesterday's data...")
# Scrape...
```

In Python shell:

```
python manage.py shell
from app.models import CreatedModel
CreatedModel.objects.all() # Shows 3000 items
```

Basically, I am wondering if those extra 1500 items in the model_data table are taking up actual space in the DB, and if so how can I erase them completely so that when I run the above query I only show 1500 items there? I'm thinking ahead as when this is actually live I'll be scraping 100K + items a day and think storage would run out fast. Also, for this specific case is using django-simple-history most prudent, or should I just keep all the data in one table and use filters when querying it in the view?

Currently, I am using the local sqlite database however hope to migrate to a remote one once I get the product up and running.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `django-simple-history` makes an extra table to *link* historical records to that record. So if you delete the object, the historical values of that record are gone as well.

Comment: Oh - okay so in reality then I should just be happy with how it's working? Since I am displaying the data I want in the HTML table, and the objects are still there to be linked to the historical table?